# Interface of my web has been changed a little after being cloned from git

Tags: html, css, laravel, git, clone

I want to put the apps from cloud server into local server by using git clone. The cloning has completed and ended successfully without any single problem. But the interface looks different in local server from the original one which is in cloud.

this is one of interface look page in cloud server
[image]

this is one of interface look page in local server
[image]

I have checked the css and html code, but nothing is different, what should I do for knowing the actual problem and what is the solution for that? thanks before

Comment: It would be nice to give more information about the framework You're using and librăries .  But it sounds like its a precompilation problem. You have to precompile the files if you are using for example SASS or LESS.

Comment: Sorry I've forgotten for telling you that, well I used laravel framework for back system and boostrap for the interface of the web app. I am still new for both of the framework, so maybe there was something I need to do or I missed because after cloning from the cloud server into local server, all the system like the button, storing data, deleting, and other functions were running normally but the interface had a little bit changed

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing some stylesheets because the font and alignments have changed in the second one, check your stylesheet paths in the document head and see if anything is throwing a 404 errors.

**TL;DR** The problem is missing styles, you just need to find where they are missing from.